# Distributed testing - jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a sample on Distributed environment on Jmeter.

Tasks performed till now :-
•   Firewall Disabled-Checked
•   Ping check to and fro for slave-master machine working fine.
•   Slave-master using same version of Jmeter – Checked
•   Set the environment variable path for Jmeter.
•   Reset the Jmeter properties file with slave machine IP.
•   Ran jmeter-server.bat on the slave machine.
Performed run from the jmeter gui by Remote Start --> selected the slave machine Ip.

Error Received :- 
exception creating connection to: 169.254.16.13; nested exception is:java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable:connect

Please provide a fix for the issue.

Comment: Are all your servers, master & slaves, on the local network (e.g., having their IPs from one of the reserved local network ranges - 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/20, 192.168.0.0/16)?

Comment: Yes, both the master and slave are in the same network.

Comment: There are quite a lot of claims they should be in the same physical subnet, in case of local networks, otherwise RMI, supposedly, failing with communications. Not sure what they are backed by, I haven't found the detailed descriptions. But what definitely works, are the SSH tunnels. In a nutshell, you're establishing three tunnels per each of your workers, with termination at the master's localhost, different ports, then point master JMeter  there.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that below ports are open and available in both the master and slave machines. [these ports can be anything]

### Slave ports:

```
Server_port=1099 
server.rmi.localport=50000
```

### Master port:

```
client.rmi.localport=60000
```

Once you setup, you should be able to telnet if the connectivity works from the master to slave. [just pinging ip confirms that master and slave are in the network. telnet confirms that they can talk to each other]

`telnet <ipaddress> <port>`

If it still does not work, setting this system property for java could help

`java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: I have changed the Slave ports and Master port in jemeter.properties. It still isn't working it displays the same error. Please let me know where to set the java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true